# What is a KEY (not PK or FK) used for on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the next SQL query:

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Genre_Movie`;
    /*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
    /*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
    CREATE TABLE `Genre_Movie` (
      `id_genre` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `id_movie` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id_movie`,`id_genre`),
      KEY `id_genre` (`id_genre`),
      CONSTRAINT `Genre_Movie_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_movie`) REFERENCES `Movie` (`id_movie`),
      CONSTRAINT `Genre_Movie_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_genre`) REFERENCES `Genre` (`id_genre`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

But I don't really know what does the following line does:

```
KEY `id_genre` (`id_genre`),
```

Can someone explain me what is the use of this line, creating a key that is not Foreign or Primary? Thanks.

Comment: It creates an index that makes searching that column faster. Foreign keys are required to be indexed (if you don't create the index explicitly, it will be created automatically when you declare the FK).

Comment: thanks, so, if I delete that line, the key would be automatically generated when doing the foreign key id_genre two lines after, nope? @Barmar

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: thanks. If you create the answer not like a comment I will give you the point. thanks again. @Barmar

Comment: Can't answer closed questions.

Comment: oh, sorry, it's closed because it is duplicated. :/

Comment: I know, I closed it.